# Как сделать такой эффект для изображения?

Tags: javascript, анимация

https://uchu-tatu.ru/ - во втором экране, в слайдере. Не могу понять, то ли это видео, то ли canvas, или js script

Comment: distorcium effect - вот здесь https://tympanus.net/codrops/2017/10/10/liquid-distortion-effects/  и на svg  это делается  тоже легко

Comment: Оно, спасибо большое!)

Comment: я щас ещё один пример покажу - он проще

Comment: @MaximLensky ничего себе легко. У меня пока только в мечтах научиться делать такое )

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/LYpMexv?editors=0010  - этот ответ был на so здесь - не могу найти - эту тему убсуждали уже

Comment: Очень классно!)))

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/KKdbZQZ - последний пример - меняйте цифры из scale и так же из values

Comment: Супер!! Спасибо,  @MaximLensky !